# in python pandas, is there anything like xbar in q?

Tags: python, pandas

for something like

```
x=[1.2 3.1 4.1 5.2 3.1], in q, there is 
xbar(x,1)
```

which turns it into

```
 [1 3 4 5 3]
```

is there anything like this in python pandas? thanks!

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.cut.html?highlight=cut#pandas.cut

Comment: i think the cut function is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as below:

```
from math import floor

x = [1.2, 3.1, 4.1, 5.2, 3.1]

y = [floor(i) for i in x]
z = [int(i) for i in x]

print(y)
# [1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 3.0]
print(z)
# [1, 3, 4, 5, 3]
```

The two list comprehensions both iterate through `x` and create a new list. For `y` the [`floor`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.floor) method is called which returns a float which has been rounded down to the nearest whole number. For `z` the [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) method rounds it down to the nearest whole number and converts to an `int` type.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'one' : pd.Series([1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1]), 'two' : pd.Series([1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1])}
d = pd.DataFrame(d)

d = d.astype(int) # Thanks to @filmor
# Or 
d = d.applymap(int)
```

Comment: Even shorter (and also faster): `d.astype(int)`

Comment: @filmor Thank you. Added you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `map` the list, like so:

```
In [2]: map(int,x)
Out[2]: [1, 3, 4, 5, 3]
```

or if you're using pandas (as your question suggests) use `astype` method or `map`:

```
In [3]: import pandas as pd

In [4]: x = pd.Series(x)

In [5]: x
Out[5]:
0    1.2
1    3.1
2    4.1
3    5.2
4    3.1
dtype: float64

In [6]: x.astype(int)
Out[6]:
0    1
1    3
2    4
3    5
4    3
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Regarding your first suggestion: In Python 3 the result will be a generator, not a `list`.